# Exposing IsLocked Field in Scratch Orgs

Tags: apex, approval-process, scratch-org, locking

I'm in the process of converting an existing project to leverage Scratch Orgs. Our Production Org uses Approval Processes extensively, and so we have some Apex that does record unlocking and locking via the Approvals API. There are also some queries that retrieve the `IsLocked` field on various objects.

```
List<Case> someCases = [SELECT Id, IsLocked FROM Case];
```

When I attempt to deploy Apex that references `IsLocked`, I get an error saying the field is not present.

```
2020-12-08 17:17:24: Error  force-app/main/default/classes/MyApexClass.cls                       SELECT Id,IsLocked FROM Case
2020-12-08 17:17:24:                                                                                       ^
2020-12-08 17:17:24:                                                                             ERROR at Row:1:Column:11
2020-12-08 17:17:24:                                                                             No such column 'IsLocked' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (74:34)
```

I get a similar error when just running SOQL queries against this new Scratch Org as well. I do have the `enableApexApprovalLockUnlock` setting enabled, and verified its set correctly in the Org as well.

When I inspect the objects in Workbench, I can see that it is present in our Production Org, but not in this Scratch Org.

[image: Production Org]

[image: Scratch Org]

Does anybody know how you enable this field?